# After building a model in Python, how do I save the model so I could shut down my computer and work on it the next day?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression

Say, I have finished building a regression model in Python, as below:

```
from sklearn import linear_model

model = linear_model.LogisticRegression().fit(X_train, Y_train)
```

How do I save the "model" that I have built so I could shut down my computer and work on it the next day without having to rerun the code to get the "model" again?

The reason why I am asking this is because my dataset is quite huge and it will take really long having to rerun to get the model again.

Comment: Aside from your question - why would you need to shut it down instead of hibernate?

Comment: I am using Anaconda. If I hibernate my computer rather than shut down and come back the next day, the "model" that I have built will still be there for me to work on? (so I don't have to rerun to get the model again)

Comment: Have you tried researching a "model registry"?

Comment: Sorry no I haven't. Can I ask what this is?

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a problem of serialisation and a very simple way would be to use the `pickle` module. The following snippets show how you can save and load a Python object.

To save:

```py
import pickle

with open("YOUR_FILE_NAME_HERE.pkl", 'wb') as file:
    pickle.dump(model, file)
```

To load:

```py
# Import all your relevant libraries first
from sklearn import linear_model
...


import pickle

with open("YOUR_FILE_NAME_HERE.pkl", 'rb') as file:
    model = pickle.load(file)
```

The idea is to essentially create a file representation of your object (`model`) and save it to file in a way that can be interpreted and loaded on demand. This can be achieved in many different ways, but the simplest method with Python is to use pickle which creates a binary representation of your object and all the associated objects and modules.

For further reading, consult the `pickle` documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) and for a better understanding of serialisation, refer to [here](https://docs.python-guide.org/scenarios/serialization/).